# Difference between a (stateless) Model and a LoadableDetachableModel

Tags: wicket

I do not see the difference between a stateless Model and a LoadableDetachableModel. 
Suppose I have:

```
    IModel<String>model=new Model<String>(){
        @Override
        public String getObject() {
            return new Date().toString();
        }
    };
    IModel<String>model2=new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return new Date().toString();
        }
    };  
    Label label = new Label("label",model);
    add(label);
    Label label2 = new Label("label2",model2);
    add(label2);
```

The first Model is stateless, so there is nothing serialized. The second LoadableDetachableModel has state, which is set to the result of  `load()`, but it is transient, so also is not serialized.

Why exists LoadableDetachableModel? A stateless Model is OK, or not? I think both are request scoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both your models do not keep any state after a request.

But your first model's `getObject()` will be called multiple times, while the `LoadableDetachableModel` is request scoped, i.e. `load()` is called once per request only.

Comment: I see. The `state` property in LoadableDetachableModels takes care that `load` is called only once. So you have to remember the result of the first call, so that is why LoadableDetachableModels has state : the `transientModelObject` (and the `state`) property. So is that the reason why  LoadableDetachableModel exists: to take care that the real work in  `getObject` is done (by means of `load`) only once?

Comment: @ericj Yes that is certainly one main reason why LoadableDetachableModel exists. For simple Models it might make pretty much no difference, but if your model does some heavier lifting like loading data from a database then it can make quite a difference if that database query is only done once per request or multiple times.